# How to get into Recovery Mode to edit /etc/fstab when I can't login as root?

Tags: grub2, fstab

I re-formatted a FAT32 partition as NTFS from Windows Server, on a dual-boot machine, and now I can't get into to Ubuntu.

Windows won't allow me to re-format it back to FAT32. And I don't have another way to boot!

I did some research and understand that the problem is the `/etc/fstab` file saying that the /data partition is `vfat`.

I can only get to grub and see its contents. So I was looking for a way to edit this file from grub. I understand me that this is not possible.

So I'm looking to get into Recovery Mode. I can make it to the **Recovery Menu**, but as soon as I hit one of the arrow keys (to select the **Drop to root shell prompt** option) I get:

```
Login incorrect

Give root password for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

Obviously, this is Ubuntu, and I don't have a root password!

I think I need to find a way to fix the Recovery Menu, but I'm losing hope.

Comment: The `grub` menu isn't a full OS, nor is an OS running when grub is active, so no you can't edit a file from grub. It's usually easier to fix issues via 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media)

Comment: Yeah, I supposed. But I don't have any other bootable media! Don't know what to do. I can't get to recovery mode either!

Comment: If the problem is really with fstab, then Ubuntu should drop you into a recovery shell (or ask for a root password to do so), from where you can edit fstab. What happens exactly when you boot?

Comment: I updated my question. I don't have a root password! And the Recovery Menu seems broken.

Comment: The 'root' password is usually the password used in initial setup for the machine, the 'administrator' user (sorry this isn't authoritative as I always change/set the password myself post-install so don't use it very often)

Comment: Yes! YEEEEESSSSSSSS!!! I tested like 47 possible old and forgotten passwords until I got it right!